# Time Complexity Solution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

Help me solve this recurrence relation

T(n) = 8T(n/2) + qn , n > 1

= p , n = 1

Answer is : n^3

Please solve by back substitution method.

The following is my attempt for the question.

[image]

Comment: Your question is more suited for website: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Using [master theorem case 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), showing `O(n^3)` is quite trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right:

```
T(n) = 8T(n/2) + qn 
=>  T(n) = 8(8T(n/4) + q(n/2)) + qn = 8^2 T(n/2^2) + q(n + 8 * n/2)
=>  T(n) = 8^2‌(8T(n/2^3) + q(n/2^2)) + q(n + 8 * n/2)
         = 8^3 T(n/2^3) + q ( n + 8 * n/2 + 8^2 * n/2^2)
```

Now by induction (if we suppose `n = 2^k` and `T(1) = 1`):

```
T(n) = q * sum_{i=0}^{k} 8^i * n / 2^i
```

Now, simplify the equation as we know `8^i / 2^i = 4^i` and by factoring `n` from the summation, we have:

```
T(n) = q * n * sum_{i=0}^{k} 4^i = q * n * (4^k - 1)
```

As `4^k = 2^{2k} = (2^k)^2 = n^2`, we can write:

```
T(n) = q * n * (n^2 - 1) = Theta(n^3)
```